# Microsoft Azure ServiceBus - How to do Request / Response?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm a little bit confused as the official documentation for the .net standard version of ServiceBus related to the request/response functionality refers to the old implementation.

`https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/QueuesRequestResponse/Server`

Is this functionality available in the .net standard 2.0 version?

Answer (score 2):

Request / Reply is a [messaging pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html) that can be implemented with both versions of the library, WindowsAzure.ServiceBus and Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus. Looks like the specific sample you're referring to was not converted. You can raise a GitHub issue to ping the team to address it.